# Bsurfaces making surfaces inside the objects in blender

Tags: modeling, add-on, topology

Im learing a way to retopologize in blender using BSurfaces, what i do is:

1. Creating a plane and going into edit mode and delete the plane.
2. I select object insted of scene from the toolbar the tool bar in grease pencil.
3. Then selecting surfaces so that the grease pencil is drawn on the surfaces of another mesh(sphere} .
4. Then pressing D and LMB i draw lines on the mesh, it goes well.
5. But when clicking on the "Add Surfaces" it doesn't draw the new surfaces on the object, it's inside it, some vertices and edges and a little bit of faces can be seen.

See the picture below what i get after clicking "Add surfaces" :

[image]

[Screenshot](https://ibb.co/mBHgzk)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that Bsurface alone keeps track of the position of the Grease Pencil strokes, but not of the faces between them: that's why it's often used in conjunction with Shrinkwrap modifier. Where did you see the "middle vetrices" automatically adjusted above the surface?

Comment: @carlo okay i used the shrink wrap modifier on the plane, and selecting target to sphere, it still doesn't make any diffrence, i cannot find any good tutorials on internet, im just combining multiple tuts, can you tell me what am i doing wrong, or just tell me a good tutorial on retopology using bsurfaces and grease pencil (short) thanks